# Presenting an operation that is for one or many items

Tags: input, experience

I have a couple of operations that can be performed on one or many items.

I can't find anything better than using a drop-down list for each of these operations or is there a more user-friendly approach for presenting them ?

[image]

**EDIT** : little typo above, *One* means "selected items", *Many* means "All items"

Comment: Could an operation be performed in a sequence:   Item1-->Done or Item2-->Done or Item3, etc.?

Comment: Yes actually that's what will happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use contextual options:
If one items is selected, display "fingerprint this item"
if multiple, "fingerprint these items"

Comment: Here's how I ended up : One button and it will perform the operation on selected items. If no items are selected, it's greyed out.

Comment: @Aybe, good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying 2 'fingerprint' buttons in the UI doesn't make sense to me.
Can you instead have 2 distinct buttons: "Fingerprint single", "Fingerprint many"?
And, use the icons you are using for "One" and "many" buttons and do away with the drop-down completely?

Comment: Yes but the problem with this is I'll have twice as many buttons as there are actions.